# Editing value from a .csv using Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a .csv file that looks somewhat like this:

```
Party    Seats    Votes

Party1   84       1584

Party2   61       851

Party3   12       100

Party4   0        82

Party5   0        29

Party6   0        15
```

I've gathered each seperate column into a list and I want to group all the parties that didnt get a seat into an "Other" party and combine their votes for a chart.

```
Party = []
Seats = []
Votes = []

for row in file:
    Party.append(row[0])
    Seats.append(row[1])
    Votes.append(row[2])

#create "other" party for 0 seat candidates
Party.append("Other")
```

I've tried using an "if" loop for seats = 0 but I think its the wrong way to go about it as it doesnt function and returns with:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance.

Below is the completed/working code for if anyone needs it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylplot as plt
import csv

outfile = open("UK_votes2017.csv","r")

file=csv.reader(outfile)
#skip the headers (party/seats/votes)
next(file, None)



#just a quick test to make sure i've read the data in.

'''for line in file:
    t=line[0], line[1], line[2]
    print(t)
'''

Party = []
Seats = []
Votes = []

others = 0

for row in file:
    if row:  # needed for the empty rows in aboves txt
        if row[1].strip() == "0":
            others += int(row[2]) # sum up 
        else:
            Party.append(row[0])
            Seats.append(row[1])
            Votes.append(row[2])

Party.append("Others") # added summed others
Seats.append("0")
Votes.append(str(others))

plt.pie(Votes, labels=Party)
plt.show()
```

[Produces this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OASV.png)

Comment: Have you considered using pandas for this?

Comment: Your current code doesn't have syntax errorr. Its occurrence is somewhere else.

Comment: What is `file`?  Please post a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parses a string (as supplied by you as example).  `' '` is used as delimiter and whitespaces after the delimiter are stripped.

It adds all `parties` to the respective lists *if* they have > 0 `seats`, else accumulates the total `other` votes.

`'Other'` is added after all `row`s are parsed and gets the accumulated total:

```
import csv

txt = '''Party    Seats    Votes

Party1   84       1584

Party2   61       851

Party3   12       100

Party4   0        82

Party5   0        29

Party6   0        15'''

Party = []
Seats = []
Votes = []

others = 0
reader = csv.reader(txt.splitlines(),  delimiter = ' ', , skipinitialspace = True)
for row in reader:
    if row:  # needed for the empty rows in aboves txt
        if row[1].strip() == "0":
            others += int(row[2]) # sum up 
        else:
            Party.append(row[0])
            Seats.append(row[1])
            Votes.append(row[2])

Party.append("Others") # added summed others
Seats.append("0")
Votes.append(str(others))

for i in range(len(Party)):
    print(Party[i], "    ", Seats[i], "    ", Votes[i])
```

Output:

```
Party      Seats      Votes
Party1      84      1584
Party2      61      851
Party3      12      100
Other       0      126
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I made a few changes to make your working relevant to the file but this is perfect, it does exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just put the conditional inline. Note that 'is' only works for int < 10, else use '==' (likely the source of your syntax error above, though you didn't include your attempt)

```
for row in file:
    Party.append('other' if row[1] is 0 else row[0])
    Seats.append(row[1])
    Votes.append(row[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your csv ( with `,` as delimiter ) :

```
Party1,84,1584
Party2,61,851
Party3,12,100
Party4,0,82
Party5,0,29
Party6,0,15
```

And :

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', sep=',', header=None)

Party = []
Seats = []
Votes = []

for value in df.values:
    Party.append('Other' if value[1] == 0 else value[0])
    Seats.append(value[1])
    Votes.append(value[2])
```